# typo3 (6.1)- Add custom attribute in <img> tag

Tags: lazy-loading, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

the background of my question is, that I want to use a "lazy load"-plugin in combination with the "photoswipe"-plugin in typo3 for a mobile website. Photoswipe works fine with typo3, but now I have to manipulate the img-tag to get lazy load to work.
The img-tag at the momant is the following:

```
<img width="546" height="364" border="0" alt="" src="..." file="fileadmin/images/.../lazyloading.gif">
```

I have to add an "attribute" to the image-tag, so that the tag looks like this:

```
<img width="546" height="364" border="0" data-rel="test" alt="" src="..." file="fileadmin/images/.../lazyloading.gif">
```

For that I tried to use the instruction on http://www.jochenfroehlich.com/typo3-tutorial/links-mit-custom-tags.html but for me it doesn't work.

You can see the "test-website" here: http://testm.alstaetter-tc.de/bilder/verschiedene

Does anybody have an idea? Thank you!

Comment: I found out how to do that: With "params"! I wrote this in typoscript: `params=data-src=fileadmin/images/mobile/Verschiedenes/thumbs/{file:current:name}` and next line this:`params.insertData=1` Then it works for me!

Comment: you can place your own solution as an answer and accept it after a while, so it looks nice :-)